# Removing element from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have a root object that hosts a `selectedFields` list. It's populated by selecting checkboxes from a populated list as well.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="root[activeSource].selectedFields[item]" ng-value="item"> {{item}}
```

Root is the main object, activeSource is the index currently being focused on. Now, this works fine, it adds fields to the list.

However, if I go back to the field list and uncheck them, it does not remove them from my object. Why is the model adding indexes, but won't remove them when it's unchecked?

Here is the root object:

```
$scope.root[value.title] = {
    "description" : value.description,
    "root" : value,
    "selectedFields" : {},
    "weight" : 0,
    "fields" : "",
    "selectedFieldsLength" : function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).length;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It set value to true/false, it can't remove entry only with ng-model and checkbox. If you want this, use a method to set and remove

OP edit: ng-change added to function. (I wrote the code, but this answer helped me write it, so giving credit where it's due)

```
//method to remove unchecked fields from active sources selected fields list
$scope.setObjectList = function() {
    //iterate fields, check for a value of false (set by model), remove if false
    angular.forEach($scope.root[$scope.activeSource].selectedFields, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key,value)
        if (key === false) {
            delete $scope.root[$scope.activeSource].selectedFields[value];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get it -- how can it add items to the list by doing that, but not remove them?

Comment: It can't remove data because it set data to false.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [ng-true-value="expression"]
       [ng-false-value="expression"]
       [ng-change="string"]>
```